# Chrome Extension stalls in "Publishing in progress"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have successfully uploaded **Test** (exposed only to tester accounts) / **Production** versions of our Google Chrome Extension using my developer account.

The problem appeared after trying to migrate our Chrome Extensions to a newly created Google Group (so as to enable collaboration for publishing different versions etc).

Now, every new version we are trying to publish stalls in ***"Publishing in progress"*** mode.

Any ideas on why this error started and how we could overcome it?

Comment: Try unpublishing it first.

Answer (score 7):

Usually it shouldn't take more than 1 hour. They did file a bug recently about somebody else in your situation:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/WaPqXFA850g

Which seems to be fixed.

Try to cancel your current publishing in progress status, and publish again. Also, make sure you update the manifest version to a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a result of the chrome web store platform itself going in some sort 
of halted stated to crunch numbers for staticial purposes.

for instance, if your extension is taking longer than usual to get published, try checking the stats for it:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/stats/{item id}

you may see that numbers for the "Impressions" and "Total Current Users" are at 0 for the current day:

[image]

This appears to be linked to longer publishing times.

Looks like you can only wait it out or republish at a different time.

related:
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/LwtIhlfwHgM
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/WaPqXFA850g