# Chrome extension not showing in the store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I published a chrome extension and you can access it only by clicking the link to chrome web store from chrome developer dashboard, but when you search it on the store you can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. You need to wait around an hour for it to register. Judging by the timestamp of the question, you should be able to see it now. For most people it will [take an hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084330/chrome-extension-stalls-in-publishing-in-progress), but some users have reported that it took [about a day](https://www.indiehackers.com/forum/how-long-does-it-take-to-publish-a-chrome-extension-e266a051a3).